# What package managers do popular Unix Distributions Use?

Tags: package-management, apt, yum, distributions

I am creating a Script and I need to know what package manager each Popular Unix Distribution Uses *(especially those distros that are commonly-used for Servers)*...

**I mean:**
*Debian uses apt-get

Fedora uses yum*

Comment: Those are package manager tools you gave as examples. An installer is a different thing.

Comment: See the Rosetta Stone for Unix http://bhami.com/rosetta.html and the Pacman Rosetta stone: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta

Comment: Yes, I meant Package Managers... Sorry for that misunderstanding!

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't work well for list-format answers like this question requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll comment about the specific *BSD tools:

- [OpenBSD](http://openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html).
- [DragonFlyBSD and NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/software/packages.html).
- [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports.html).

Warning: the *BSD systems use the same name convention for the tools (pkg_add, pkg_info, etc) but all are completely different.

Comment: OK! Thanks for your answer! I got what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

You would probably be better off creating a .deb package for Debian based distros (including Ubuntu), and .rpm package for Red-Hat based distros (including Fedora), and making the .tar file available for everybody else. Don't concern yourself with which package manager each distro uses. For instance, although I run a Debian-derived distro, I personally use the `aptitude` package manager. But and .deb package will install for me, assuming that it targets the versions of dependencies that I have installed.

Comment: These package managers are used IN my script!
So, I need to know which one each OS uses...

Comment: I see. Then you need less concern yourself with which package manager is the 'default' for that distro, and just worry about which package managers are available. I would target apt-get, yum, zipper, and pacman.

Answer (score 0):

The website [distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=package-management) compares the package manager tools and their options of all famous linux distributions.

Answer (score -1):

Its different for different unix-systems. But the common thing in all those is the tar.gz file . It is the source code of your program. Then you can make either .deb files for Debian systems or .rpm file for Red Hat Systems. The .deb and .rpm are both binary files while tar.gz is mostly ASCII file but it can also contain binaries. You can convert .rpm file to .deb file in debian systems by this command:

To install :

> sudo apt-get install alien

To convert to .deb from .rpm :

> sudo alien "packagename.rpm"

Replace the "packagename.rpm" with your original name of the file.

Then a .deb file will be created and to install that use :

> sudo dpkg -i "filename.deb"

Replace the "filename.deb" with your original name of the file.

If you want that users can install your application by apt-get or yum then you will have to upload your app to the repository of your distribution. Only then the user will be able to use apt-get or yum to install the application directly.

Comment: A `tar.gz` file is not necessarily source code; it can contain binaries, and it's definitely not an ASCII file: it's a gzip-compressed archive.

Comment: sorry wait I will edit it!

Comment: It is still incorrect. A `tar.gz` is a compressed file that contains multiple files within it. There is no reason to expect them to be source files.